# 基本的なサンプルページの表示が上手くいかない

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

基本的なことで大変恐縮です。

http://components.onsen.io/patterns

これの上段中央（犬とおじさん）の画面なんですが「Profile」の文字が中央にいきません。
プレビューではちゃんと表示されるのですがビルドする「Profile」の文字が左によってしまいます。
プロジェクトは最小限のテンプレートです。

どなたかご教授いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 私は実機ビルドができないのでお力にはなれそうもないのですが、事象が発生している端末（Android, iOS, Windows）、OSのバージョン等の情報があると回答が得やすいように思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onsen UIのons-toolbarを使う場合、Androidで実行するとタイトル部分が自動的に左寄せになります。これは、Androidではネイティブのツールバーのタイトルが左寄せになるのがデフォルトであるのでそれに合わせているからです。

この動作を抑制したい(タイトルを中央寄せにしたい)場合には、ons-toolbarにfixed-style属性を追加するとうまくいくと思います。

```
<ons-toolbar fixed-style>
...
</ons-toolbar>
```

http://ja.onsen.io/reference/ons-toolbar.html#attributes